# Register an UserControl in another UserControl with ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, user-controls

I want to register an UserControl in another UserControl but i have some errors like :

> Control '4_txtCount' of type
>   'NumbericTextBox' must be placed
>   inside a form tag with runat=server.
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> **Exception Details:**
>   System.Web.HttpException: Control
>   '4_txtCount' of type 'NumbericTextBox'
>   must be placed inside a form tag with
>   runat=server

And when i add a server side from tag in my UserControl, i never get the error message.

Please note that i already add a server side form tag in my View...

How can i register and use an UserControl in another UserControl without adding server side form tag in UserControl?

Thanks, Afshin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "UserControl" I assume you're referring to a Partial View. One of the controls you're using in your Partial View is an ASP.NET web forms control. You cannot use a control that requires a postback. No MVC View should require a form runat=server tag. If the control you're trying to use isn't designed for use in an MVC environment, consider creating a route using WebForm Routing (System.Web.Routing) for that page specifically:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202(v=vs.90).aspx

You can modify the RouteHandler constructor to accept an object you've populated with the necessary data. The ViewData dictionary is not available in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `form` tag inside the user control.

Just ensure that the resulting page, where the user control is being placed has a `form` tag surrounding the user control.

The `form` tag could be placed on the ASPX page or the master page of the ASPX page.

Comment: As i say in my question, i already added an server side form tag but still i get error message...